What tape/adhesive to hold together a cardboard diverter
I have a through-the-wall air conditioner (example). Since it sits near the floor, I've fashioned a diverter out of cardboard panels that sticks into the air vents and directs cold air upwards.
The cardboard panels are held together by some transparent plastic tape, but the tape eventually detaches and the diverter falls apart. I thought the tape was poor so I redid the seams with "extra strength" tape but it fell apart after a few months again.
I noticed the cold air chills the diverter edges enough for moisture and frost to form on the tape. I'm thinking this might be causing the adhesive to work poorer than expected.
I've looked in to "cardboard" tapes but they seem to be targeted towards packaging.
What would be the best tape or adhesive to hold together cardboard panels in such conditions, cold and moist?

duct tape .....

Why not use something a little sturdier (and waterproof) than cardboard, like corrugated twinwall plastic sheeting and glue the panels together?

It's cardboard, so it's all temporary.  Choosing a tape that is better suited is wise.
Use HVAC Foil tape it is made for hvac use and will stand up to cold temps.

Old-school brown paper gum tape, kind of a hassle to find it though.  it's still used industrially... but I wouldn't know whjere to buy it. and then you'ew stuck with an industrioal sized roll of wet before use gummed tape.
Instead cut some tape sized strips from a brown paper bag and wet one side with white glue (PVA).  it should work about as well as the gum tape.
